# ImportError with subprocess, run and PIPE in python

Tags: python, sdk, aapt

I'm using subprocess in python with this code :

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE
result = run(['/Users/{PATH-TO-SDK}/28.0.3/aapt','dump', 'badging', 'com.squareup.cash.apk'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, check=True,
    universal_newlines=True)
version = result.stdout.split("versionName='")[1].split("'")[0]
```

This code used to work with Mac but when I'm using it on ubuntu I've got an error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "ScrapInfos.py", line 11, in 
>       from subprocess import run, PIPE
>   ImportError: cannot import name run

How can I fix this ? Thank you

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api), there are some differences when trying to use `run` depending on the Python version. Which version are you running in both platforms?

Comment: Also, according to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module), `run` was added in Python 3.5 so in order to use it you will need to have Python >= 3.5 installed.

Answer (score 0):

`run` may be defined already; use `subprocess.run` instead.

```py
import subprocess 
from subprocess import PIPE

command = [
    '/Users/{PATH-TO-SDK}/28.0.3/aapt',
    'dump', 
    'badging', 
    'com.squareup.cash.apk',
]
result = subprocess.run(command, 
        stdout=PIPE, 
        stderr=PIPE, 
        check=True, 
        universal_newlines=True)

version = result.stdout
version = version.split("versionName='")[1]
version = version.split("'")[0]
```